# При работе с Excel программа завершается

Tags: c#, uwp

Работаю с Excel (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel). При вводе любого кода программа крашится. Вот код: `Excel.Application ex = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();` 
Ошибка происходит вот тут: `if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` (файл: App.g.i.cs)

Comment: Текст ошибки?,,

Comment: Программа вылетает, не показывая ошибку. а просто открывает файл App.g.i.cs, подсвечивая эту строку: if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Comment: удалите строку, и все, что внутри этого `if`

Comment: Зачем вы вообще упоминаете Excel, если ваш вопрос с ним никак не связан? У вас возникли проблемы с дебаггером.

Comment: Жалуется на то что изменен файл App.g.i.cs

Comment: Ну так ошибка появляется при работе с Excel

Comment: Смотрите документацию: [Debugger.Break](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.break). В коде написано `Break` - именно это и происходит. Это в том случае, если дебаггер подключен. Запустите программу без отладки - `if` не выполнится.

Comment: System.IO.FileLoadException: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)" Выдает следующую ошибку

Comment: Правило этого сайта: одна тема - один вопрос. Разделите свой вопрос на два: один по Debugger (отредактируйте его, удалив все упоминания Excel). другой - по проблеме с Excel (создайте новую тему).